# Wrong result mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I've got a problem. I just want return the users (`benutzername`) and the `game_id` (`spiel_id`) from a database.

My select gimme the usernames, but also all `spiel_ids` and not the special for the users.

It's like:

```
username Game_Id
a          1
b          1
c          1
a          2
b          2
c          2
```

and so on.

but the result has to be something like this:

```
a       3
b       1
c       5
```

my select is looking like:

```
SELECT Benutzer.benutzername, Spiel.Spiel_ID
FROM Benutzer, Spiel
WHERE Benutzer_ID IN
    (SELECT Benutzer_ID_1
    FROM Spiel WHERE NextToPlay ='35'
    AND Benutzer_ID_2 ='35')
OR
    Benutzer_ID IN
    (SELECT Benutzer_ID_2
    FROM Spiel WHERE NextToPlay ='35'
    AND Benutzer_ID_1 ='35');
```

Comment: You don't have a join condition. You need to put a predicate that will put a correlation between a `Benutzer` and a corresponding `Spiel`

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to :

```html
Select * from Spiel;

select Spiel_ID, benutzername from Spiel, Benutzer
where nexttoplay='34'
AND Benutzer_ID_1 = '34'
AND Benutzer.benutzer_ID = Spiel.Benutzer_ID_2
;
```

But in Spiel is a column named Benutzer_ID_1, where i have to check, if there is a '34' too.